# Python Want to move/Create a text file into a folder with the same name

Tags: python, directory

I have a series of text files that are named with a series of numbers (20040719.txt) that I need edited and placed into folders with the same name as the text file (but without the .txt in the folder name). I am able to do my edits and create the folders with the correct names, but can't seem to get the edited files into their corresponding folders. There are no errors, so my question is how can i do this type of file move.

here is what I have so far

> import glob
> import os
> import shutil
>
> list_of_files = glob.glob("f:/Python scripts/Tests2/*.txt")
>
> root_path = 'f:/Python scripts/Tests2/'
>
> for file_name in list_of_files:
>
> ```
> folders = [file_name.replace('.txt', 'D')]
>
> for folder in folders:
>     os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))
>
> input = open(file_name, 'r')
> output = open(file_name.replace('.txt', 't2.txt'), "w")                
>
> for line in input:       
>     str = line.strip("    dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss         kA\t")
>     str = str.replace("date", "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss")
>     str = str.replace("lat.   long.   amp.", "    lat long    ka")
>     output.write(str)
>
> input.close()
> output.close()
> ```
>
> list_of_folders = glob.glob("f:/Python scripts/Tests2/*D")
>
> list_of_t2txt = glob.glob("f:/Python scripts/Tests2/*t2.txt")
>
> for Folder_Name in list_of_folders:
>
> ```
> for t2txt_Name in list_of_t2txt:
>
>     if  t2txt_Name.replace('*t2.txt', '*D') == Folder_Name:
>         shutil.move(t2txt_Name, Folder_Name)
> ```

the end 'if' statement was a trial to see if I could do it that way

Comment: Do you get an error statement when you run it?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't just post code and say "this doesn't work; what's wrong?". What happens when you run it?

Comment: What code you have posted looks seriously screwed up with odd indenting and lines that have been run together. You'll need to do better than that if you want anyone to take your question seriously.

Comment: Fixed some of my posting errors, also tried to clean up the indenting but the pasting didnt do a very good job.